# SCPでのファイル転送について

Tags: scp

SCPでローカル（以下、「サーバーA」とします）からリモート（以下、「サーバーB」とします）へSCPの `-pr` オプションを利用して、ディレクトリごと、ファイルの属性を維持して、ファイルを転送したいと考えています。

この際、サーバーBに存在しないファイルのみ転送し、なおかつサーバーBにあるファイルより更新日時が新しいファイルのみ転送したいと考えています。
このような転送を行う場合、何かよい方法はありますでしょうか。
また、SCPで難しい場合、他によい方法はあるでしょうか。

ちなみに、rsyncは相手方サーバーに入っていないため、利用できません。
何かアドバイスをいただけると幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ローカルサーバ側に [sshfs: A network filesystem client to connect to SSH servers](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) をインストールして、リモートサーバ側の転送先ディレクトリをローカルサーバ側にマウントする方法が考えられます。この場合、scp ではなく cp コマンドを使います。`cp -upr src_dir dest_dir` (GNU cp 以外の場合、`-u` オプションが用意されていないかもしれません)

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速試してみましたが、ローカルとリモートでユーザー名が違うためか、パーミッションが600や700に変更されてしまいます。何か対処法はありますでしょうか。ちなみに、「-p」オプションを除いたところ、パーミッションがおかしくなることはありませんでしたが、今度は更新日時が維持されないようです。なお、「-p」オプションをつけてコピーすると、「cp: '/home/local_user/remote_server/xxx/yyy' の所有者の保護に失敗しました: 許可がありません」のようなエラーが表示されています。

Comment: sshfs のオプションに `-o idmap=user,uid=local_user_uid,gid=local_user_gid` を追加してみて下さい。`local_user_uid` と `local_user_gid` は整数値で指定します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたところ、ファイルは大丈夫そうでしたが、ディレクトリのパーミッションが0755ではなく、0700になってしまうようです。

Comment: 手元の環境ではディレクトリのパーミッションは変化しないのですが、sshfs のオプションに `default_permissions` を追加して試していただけますか。`sshfs -o default_permissions,idmap=user,...`

Comment: ありがとうございます。オプションを追加して試してみましたが、やはりうまくいかないようです。もしかして、sshfsのバージョンが問題でしょうか。こちらのバージョンは2.8です。

Comment: こちらは 2.10 です。

Comment: [こちら](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues/26)を参考にオプションをいくつか指定したところうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 事例として関心がありますので、具体的にどの様なオプション指定にして上手くいったのかを回答として投稿してもらえますか？(自身の回答を承認する事が可能です)

Comment: 一応、かなり簡単ではありますが、回答として投稿しておきました。

Comment: ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

一応解決したので、こちらに残しておきます。

今回は、SSHFSをインストールして、リモートサーバーをローカルサーバーにマウントしてコピーする方法をとりました。
ちなみに、こちらの環境の問題かもしれませんが、sshfsでマウントする際、`readdir_ino` をつけないと、コピー時にディレクトリのパーミッションが維持されないようです。